# apply substitute to a string variable in a map

Tags: vim

I have a `noremap` that sends the current full file path to an interpreter.

The problem is that on windows the `\` need to be `/` -- so when i pass `expand("%:p")` an error is thrown.

I have figured how to do this with a string in the editing frame in vim using `:s@\\@/@g`, however, i cannot figure out how to apply the substitute command to the string before sending it from vim to the interpreter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `substitute()` function that works like `:s`: Just use `substitute(expand("%:p"), '\\', '/', 'g')`. However, for this particular character swap, the simpler `tr()` will suffice: `tr(expand("%:p"), '\', '/')`.

Actually, a simple substitution can actually be combined with `expand()` (thanks Peter Rincker for the comment!), through a rather obscure feature of filename-modifiers: `expand('%:p:gs?\\?/?')`.

Also, have a look at `:set shellslash`; it can globally translate backslashes into forward slashes on Windows.

Comment: +1 / accepted ... thanks (of course it's possible ... this is `vim` :)

Comment: You can to the expand and substitute in one command: `expand('%:p:gs?\\?/?')`. See `:h filename-modifiers` for more information.